# MS SQL optimal execution plan compiling abort due time out

Tags: sql-server, timeout

I have two tables (Table1, Table2) and Id from Table1 is a foreign key in Table2. Both tables have trigger on delete updating other table (Table3). Delete on Table1 cascade delete on Table2. When i execute

```
delete from Table1 
where  Table4Id = @table4Id
```

i'am getting compilation timeout on Table2 trigger

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
    CPU time = 391 ms, elapsed time = 10726 ms.

StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="TimeOut"
```

On delete trigger from Table1

```
UPDATE table3 
SET    table3.Column1 = NULL 
FROM Table3 AS table3
  JOIN DELETED AS deleted ON deleted.Table4Id = table3.Table4Id
WHERE deleted.Column1 = 1
```

On delete trigger from Table2

```
UPDATE table3 
SET    table3.Column1 = NULL 
FROM   Table1 AS table1
  JOIN DELETED AS deleted on deleted.Table1Id = table1.Id
  JOIN Table3 AS table3 ON deleted.Table3Id = table3.Id
WHERE table1.Column1 = 1 AND table1.Table4Id = table3.Table4Id
```

Is there a way to get rid of this compile timeout?

Comment: I guess this could be because of your cascade delete you force both delete triggers to update the same field in the same table in the same transaction. Both triggers are trying to lock it to update it, but have to wait on each other.

Comment: executing a delete statement does not compiles anything. Do you get the error when you hit F5 on "delete from table1..." or when you hit F5 on "create trigger ..." ?

Comment: I'm getting this timeout when i hit F5 on "delete from Table1 ..."

Comment: so you are not getting errors when compiling, you are not compiling anything

Comment: you are deleting records, not compiling anything. The triggers on your cascaded tables are firing and since they are both trying to lock the same table you get a timeout. Look at my answer, get rid of the triggers, get rid of the cascade delete, and create an instead of trigger on table1

Comment: Why triggers? You can do the same thing with stored procedures. More easy to debug, better maintenance, self-documented and you have the absolute control.

Comment: A stored procedure is not automatic. It is up to the programmer to call it or not. In this case a trigger is better, but he needs to create only one instead of trigger in stead of 2 triggers

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get rid of this compile timeout?

This is not an issue and this has been described by Benjamin Nevarej here:[The Phases of Query Optimization](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/ben_nevarez/archive/2009/08/20/the-phases-of-query-optimization.aspx)

Query Optimizer is a cost  based optimizer and when we present a query,it can go through different phases depending on query complexity.Those phases are

Phase 0--Transaction processing
Phase 1 --quick plan
Phase 2--full optimization

and also one more phase called Timeout ,below is the explanation of timeout phase

> The DMV can also show a timeout event. When a timeout is found, the Query Optimizer stops the optimization process and returns the least expensive plan it has found so far. This timeout event is also shown on the properties of a graphical plan as Reason For Early Termination of Statement Optimization or on an XML plan as StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason.

You can look at all the phases using below DMV as well

```
sys.dm_exec_query_optimizer_info
```

[Paul White](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/04/28/query-optimizer-deep-dive-part-2.aspx) also confirms the same in his blog..

> The optimizer also sets a budget at the start of a phase for the number of optimization ‘moves’ it considers sufficient to find a pretty good plan (remember the optimizer’s goal is to find a good enough plan quickly).  If the process of exploring and implementing alternatives exceeds this ‘budget’ during a phase, the phase terminates with a ‘Time Out’ message.  **Early termination (for whatever reason) is part of the optimizer’s design, completely normal, and not generally a cause for concern**.

Further reading..

[Query Optimizer Deep Dive](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/04/28/query-optimizer-deep-dive-part-1.aspx) series by Paul white

Answer (score 0):

Because of our cascade delete you have 2 triggers that are updating the same column in the same record of the same table at the same time. Each of them wants to lock it but has to wait for the other and that gives you a timeout.

Cascade delete is never a good idea, better is to write an **instead of** trigger for delete on table1, which can delete the child records in table2 and do all the loggging that is needed.

Comment: I'm getting timeout during compilation. Updating same record shouldn't affect compiling time.

Comment: then update your question that you get the error during compilation. You wrote you get the error when you execute this : delete from Table1 
where  Table4Id = @table4Id

Comment: Also during which compilation do you get the error ? on the trigger of table1 or on the trigger of table2 ? or somewhere else ? I cannot see that in your question

Comment: It's the trigger on Table2

Comment: you are deleting records, not compiling anything. The triggers on your cascaded tables are firing and since they are both trying to lock the same table you get a timeout. Look at my answer, get rid of the triggers, get rid of the cascade delete, and create an instead of trigger on table1